# Maximizing functions with Which statements

Tags: programming, mathematical-optimization, conditional

I'd like to be able to find the maximum value that my Capex function (see below) generates. This is a fairly simple function so I could just add it up but I have more complex functions of a similar form that I'll need to maximize.

```
Capex[romSize_, CCSPsize_, washRate_, miningRate_] :=
Module[{val, rom = romSize, CCSP = CCSPsize, wash = washRate},
val = 0;
Which[CCSP > 500, val = val - 100];
Which[rom >= 200 && rom < 300, val = val - 5, rom >= 300, 
 val = val - 10];
Which[wash >= 1300 && wash < 1500, val = val - 10, wash >= 1500, 
val = val - 20];
Which[miningRate >= 5.5 && miningRate < 5.7, val = val - 10, 
miningRate >= 5.7, val = val - 20];
Return[val]
];
```

The problem  I have is that because it contains Which statements the Maximize function doesn't seem to work. I could spam the Capex function with values in the domain and pick the largest value but I was hoping Mathematica had some functionality to make it a little easier, kind of like Goal Seek in Excel.

An example of a simple maximize call would be

```
Maximize[{Capex[x, 600, 1500, 6], 120 <= x <= 300}, {x}]
```

The max value of -240 is correct but x=300 is not

Comment: I'm getting $x=120$ as the value from `Maximize[]`; have a look at `Plot[Capex[x, 600, 1500, 6], {x, 120, 300}]` to see why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're not using `Which` for more complex constructs or using a "default value", I suggest discarding the `Which` construct and instead adopting a far simpler approach to defining your `Capex` function:

```
capex[rom_, CCSP_, wash_, mining_] :=
    -100 ( CCSP   >  500                 ) +
    -5   ( rom    >= 200  && rom < 300   ) +
    -10  ( rom    >= 300                 ) +
    -10  ( wash   >= 1300 && wash < 1500 ) +
    -20  ( wash   >= 1500                ) +
    -10  ( mining >= 5.5  && mining < 5.7) +
    -20  ( mining >= 5.7                 ) /. {True -> 1, False -> 0}
```

or as J. M. notes, using `Boole` and `Dot`:

```
capex[rom_, CCSP_, wash_, mining_] := 
    {-100, -5, -10, -10, -20, -10, -20}.Boole[{CCSP > 500, 200 <= rom < 300, 300 <= rom, 
         1300 <= wash < 1500, 1500 <= wash, 5.5 <= mining < 5.7, 5.7 <= mining}]
```

You can verify that the above and your function return the same value for the same input.

Comment: As an alternative implementation: `capex[rom_, CCSP_, wash_, mining_] := {-100, -5, -10, -10, -20, -10, -20}.Boole[{CCSP > 500, 200 <= rom < 300, 300 <= rom, 1300 <= wash < 1500, 1500 <= wash, 5.5 <= mining < 5.7, 5.7 <= mining}]`

Comment: I can confirm that it returns the same value. Is there an easy way to maximize your capex function?

Comment: @Cam Why isn't it working for you? `NMaximize[{capex[x, 600, 1500, 6], 120 <= x <= 300}, {x}]` gives me `{-140., {x -> 120.911}}`

Comment: I've modified my capex function to use the Boole function and that worked when I tried to maximize it. Thanks for the help guys, it would have taken me ages to figure that one out by myself.

Comment: @Cam: you might also be interested in the functions `ArgMax[]` and `MaxValue[]`, if you only need particular components of the output of `Maximize[]`.